# jQuery Autocomplete not persisting values during ASP.NET postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, postback

I have a really simple problem that I am struggling to find a solution for.

Basically I have an ASP.NET textbox declared as such.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCourse" CssClass="input-xlarge HighlightibleField" placeholder=""></asp:TextBox>
```

Onto this textbox I have bound a the jQuery UI autocomplete widget like this.

```
$("#<% =txtCourse.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
    source: ["Course1", "Course2", "Course3"],
    select: function (event, ui) {
        __doPostBack("<% =btnPostBacker.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
});
```

The postback occurs as expected however the txtCourse.Text will not persist (or postback) the value that it was populated with.

So for example, I go ahead and select "Course1", the value is populated into the txtCourse textbox, the postback occurs and I view the value of txtCourse.Text and it will still be only the text that I have inputted using the keyboard (eg: "c").

I have tried setting a timer to delay the execution of the postback ever so slightly as such:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    __doPostBack("<% =btnPostBacker.UniqueID %>", "");
}, 500);
```

And while this seems to work, I feel it shouldn't be necessary and have no idea why it is required.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: right before the postback, set the value on TextBox, something like        `$("#<% =txtCourse.ClientID %>").value(SelectedValue)` so the text box post that value and keep it after the post back. If not happens, means that you change the textbox value on code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to post the item selected?

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    __doPostBack("<% =btnPostBacker.UniqueID %>", ui.item);
}
```

EDIT: or perhaps:

```
  select: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).val(ui.item);
        __doPostBack("<% =btnPostBacker.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
```

Comment: Spot on... Your post made me realize the value obviously wasn't being set until after the event completed and this workaround appears to have resolved it. Thank you very much...